# Visual Studio 2017 symbol underlinings

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

I have a very large customer project in C# and I'm using Visual Studio 2017.

My problem is that Visual Studio has underlined some of my symbols "are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?". I can still compile and run the project so I don't understand what the problem might be and how to fix it. In C++ if you are in similar situation the code won't compile at all.

**Edit: Visual Studio 2015 seems to work properly**

Comment: I also faced similar issue. But i think its because VS17 taking some time to load all projects and files. untill it loads all files it shows red lines as compile time errors

Comment: I don't think it should take several days to load the project :)

Comment: Have you referenced another project in the solution or a dll library directly? Have you tried to remove and re-add the reference?

Comment: I don't know. I haven't written this software and there are hundreds of subprojects. Intellisense actually works properly in VS2015 but not in VS2017. So this is typical buggy MS garbage I'm afraid. Google finds a lot of similar mysterious issues.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your project, but a (quite general) solution may be:

Deleting **bin** and **debug** folders and building again.